# Join element from array if the array element length is less than 5

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I am trying to join the next array element together to single element from array if the element of the array is less than length 4. It should add to the next element index.

Another logic is, if the next consecutive array length is also less then 4 char then it joins the next array element also up to 3 times in total. I want to implement this. It's getting complex for me I am not understand this logic.

This is the code, here it has array on `titleList`, now we have to use the above logic in this array list.

```
@foreach (var title in randomtitle)  
{
   </span>@titleList.ElementAt(title)</span>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string theTitle { get; set; }
    private string[] titleList = Array.Empty<string>();

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {  
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(theTitle))
        {
            titleList = theTitle.Split(" ");
        }
    }

    private Random random = new();
    
    private IEnumerable<int> randomtitle =>
        Enumerable.Range(0, titleList.Count() - 1) // { 0, 1, 2, 3 } generate sequence
            .OrderBy(x => random.Next())      // { 3, 1, 0, 2 } random shuffle
            .Take(2)                          // { 3, 1 }       pick two
            .ToList();
}
```

Comment: I totally don't understand what you are trying to achieve. You are saying that you want to join arrays but nowhere in the code you are attempting to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for a method that does following:

- take a collection of strings(like a `string[]`)
- iterate each string and check if it's length is greater than or equal 4
- if so, everything is fine, take it as it is
- if not, append the next to the current string and check their length afterwards
- if they are still not greater than or equal 4 append the next one, but max 3 times

Then this should work (not tested well though):

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2uHREv

```
static string[] MergeItems(IList<string> all, int minLength, int maxGroupCount)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>(all.Count);
    for(int i = 0; i < all.Count; i++)
    {
        string current = all[i];
        if(i == all.Count - 1)
        {
            list.Add(current);
            break;            
        }

        if (current.Length < minLength)
        {
            for (int ii = 1; ii < maxGroupCount && i + ii < all.Count; ii++)
            {
                int nextIndex = i + ii;
                string next = all[nextIndex];
                current = current + next;
                if (current.Length >= minLength || ii+1 == maxGroupCount)
                {
                    list.Add(current);
                    i = nextIndex;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            list.Add(current);
        }
    }

    return list.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tim, but my requirement  was to do this with same array, I mean we will have 1 array in total and we compare the 1 array with the next element of an array and if lenth is less then 3 then it joins for total 3 times. 

Here in your code you used 2 array can you please update the code with 1 array only using ?

Comment: @Arjun, you are supposed to copy the `MergeItems` method and call it passing your own list as parameter: `titleList = MergeItems(titleList, 4, 3);`